# Iteration (filtering out specific letters) using getchar in C

Tags: c, for-loop, iteration

I'm new to C and I had written the following code:

```
for(i=0; i<25; ++i) {
    ch=getchar();
    if (ch == 'A' || ch == 'B'|| ch == 'C'|| ch == 'D'|| ch == 'a'|| ch == 'b'|| ch == 'c'|| ch == 'd'){
    putchar(toupper(ch));
    }
}
```

I expect my code to filter out the letters "a,b,c and d" AND show them as an output if and only if there is an A that can be paired with B (same for B) and C that can be paired with D. (output in uppercase)

I used for loop for this so that it would get the letters each time it enters the loop.

I do not want my code to include arrays.

An example input and expected output:

input: *ATASHPPOTCBD*
output: *ACBD*

It writes the first A because it's able to pair it with B but not the second A. Also it writes the C and D because they were able to be paired.

Comment: Can you please *edit your question* to show some example input, and the expected (and actual) output?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude added, thanks for the feedback!

Comment: So if I understand you correct, when you find the first `'A'` you search for the first `'B'`, and when you find the second `'A'` you search for a possible second `'B'`. If the second `'A'` doesn't have a matching second `'B'` the `'A'` is not printed. Is that correct? If so, you can't do it using only a single loop, you need nested loops for the searching of the `'B'`. And you need to keep track of which `'A'` (first, second, third etc.) you currently have, to know which `'B'` to find.

Comment: exactly, you got it right. And I am goint to use nested loops but I am having a hard time trying to build up the algorithm, since I am not capable of finding the first the A and looking for the first B.

Comment: Your question is under-specified, still.  It seems you should ignore and not print any characters except A, B, C or D (or their lower-case counterparts).  It isn't clear whether you have to be ready to treat a gigabyte file or only single lines, and how long single lines might be.  It appears that you have to keep  a record of the sequence of interesting letters, so that you can determine how to print them.  You mention 'same for B', but it isn't clear what that means.  What should be the output from 'BADC'?  What should be the output from 'AAAAAAAABCCCCDDDDDDDDDDDDCC? Guess: 'ABCCCCDDDD'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some simple pseudo-code that shows a possible algorithm:

```
read_all_input_into_a_string();

current_A = 0;

for(each character in the string)
{
    if (character == 'A')
    {
        ++current_A;
        current_B = 0;
        for (each character2 in the string)
        {
            if (character2 == 'B')
            {
                ++current_B;
                if (current_A == current_B)
                {
                    // Found matching A and B
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you should not start over from the beginning of the string when searching for a matching `'B'` then just start from the position where you found the `'A'`.

Comment: is there a way to do it without saving the input on memory? like, not using strings?

Comment: @Stekker If the file is large, or you have very limited memory, then you could save the file-position when you find `'A'`, and after searching for `'B'` you seek back to that position. And instead of iterating over the characters in the string, you of course reads characters from the file. Saving into a string will be more efficient than jumping back and forth through the file.